# How to convert XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 to XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, azure-integration-account

I am working on standard logic apps.  In that I am not able to use the XSLT2.0 and XSLT 3.0. The Standard logic app will allows only XSLT1.0 . so what is the best approach to convert XSLT2.0 and XSLT3.0 in to XSLT 1.0

I have XSLT3.0 and XSLT 2.0.  How should I use those XSLT files in my standard logic app?

Comment: Is that restriction to XSLT 1.0 a technical one (because "standard" means .NET standard/.NET core and whoever integrated XSLT 2 or 3 into Azure is not aware of SaxonCS or IKVM compiled Saxon HE for .NET core) or is that just a term Microsoft uses for a certain, inexpensive package and they also offer a perhaps more expensive package that includes XSLT 2 and/or 3 support but your budget doesn't allow that? Anyway, conversion of XSLT 2 or 3 code to XSLT 1 is not going to be automatic and could end up being as expensive or more expensive than perhaps using a logic app/pack with XSLT 2/3 support.

Answer (score 2):

If the XSLT uses few XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 3.0 advances, and you are a sophisticated XSLT developer, then work your way through

- [What's New in XSLT 2.0?](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#whats-new-in-xslt2)
- [What’s New in XSLT 3.0?](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#whats-new-in-xslt3)

and adapt each in-play XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 concept and construct back to XSLT 1.0.  There is no automated conversion solution, and this is not a task suitable for a developer unfamiliar with XSLT.

Otherwise, your options include:

1. Use a more modern framework that supports modern tools, or
2. Find a way to incorporate an XSLT 3.0 processor into your framework.  (Consider Saxonica's products, which support a [plethora of platforms](https://www.saxonica.com/products/platforms.xml)), or
3. Apply the XSLT 2.0/3.0 transformation in another stage of your pipeline outside of the weak tool that only supports ancient XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0/3.0 support for Azure Logic App (Standard) is apparently on its way.

From [Dan Toomey](https://twitter.com/daniel2me) (Microsoft Azure MVP) slides at Integrate 2022:

```
Logic App (Standard) Note: Support for XSLT 2.0/3.0 is in private preview
```

Here's the the slide in question: [Options at a Glance](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/dantoomey-integrate2022-shared-220615134332-62189df2/75/integrate-2022-data-mapping-in-the-microsoft-cloud-42-2048.jpg?cb=1667450796). It may be worthwhile seeing if you can join the private preview?

Comment: Looks like it's now GA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-maps?tabs=consumption#limitations